# Using plot directive in Sphinx with testcode in docstring

Tags: python-sphinx

Is there a way to incorporate the `.. plot::`  directive in Sphinx with the `.. testcode::` one?

When using doctest type I can integrate them like (just general idea):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.array([0,1,2])

.. plot::
    plt(x)
    plt.show()

>>> print(x)
[0,1,2]
```

Then a figure would be inserted above the example output.  Instead of using the `>>>`, can one do something more like:

```
.. testcode:: *
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    x = np.array([0,1,2])

.. plot::
    plt(x)
    plt.show()

.. testcode:: *
    print(x)

.. testoutput:: *
[0,1,2]
```

When I try something like the one above, the plot directive does not have access to `x`, and doesn't seem to allow the groups option.